# How to Manage my Comment System in Using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]

Please I need help. Am designing a web app that makes use of MySQl databse with tables as shown above. How do I select the comments from the comment table and join with member table as to display the commants along with the username that corresponds with user_id thus:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql would be as so:

```
$usercomment = $conn->query("select m.usename, c.comment
                            from member m
                            join comment c
                            on m.id = c.user_id");
```

and you would pull the data something like this:

```
while ($row = $usercomment->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row['comment'].' by .'row['username'].<br/>';
}
```